# Some Experience Editor icons are missing after upgrade to 9.0 Update 1

Tags: experience-editor, upgrade

After upgrading from 8.1 Update 3 to latest 9.0 Update 1 a lot of icons are missing in the Experience Editor, but not all.

[image: experience editor]

For example on the **PRESENTATION** tab only the **Preview** and **Normal** icons are showing up as you can see. The default Save/Search/New Component (top left) and the ribbon fold up/down icon (top right) are also missing.

I've tried to disable most of our custom code and tried with a clean installation (webroot only, not databases). I've also cleared my cached etc. but without any luck.

There are no failed requests being made (Chrome developer tools).

The buttons with missing icons just have a `<div>` with a class indicating some sort of sprite.

```
<div title="Edit the current page." class="sprite-speak-ribbon-clean-ee edit_24">
</div>
```

The functioning icons have an `<img>`.

```
<img alt="Open Browser as normal" src="/temp/iconcache/office/24x24/eye.png">
```

Does anyone have an idea about what is going on or where to dig deeper?

Comment: Did you use Express Migration tool? I did an upgrade recently from 7.1 to 8.2 Update-5 and I used Express Migration tool. I've noticed some missing icons as well. I used Razl to compare the upgraded instance with a fresh installation and noticed that some items in the core database got the '/temp/' path in the icon fields. I used Razl to overwrite these messy '/temp/' and it was fixed.

Comment: I did not use the Express Migration tool as our version was not supported. I've digged a little deeper and it would appear that not all the sprite files are being generated (only `sprite-speak-ribbon-base-ee.css` but not `sprite-speak-ribbon-clean-ee.css` and `sprite-speak-ribbon-clean-ee.png`)

Comment: What if you install a fresh Sitecore 9.0 Update-1 and attach the migrated databases? You deploy the Visual Studio solution - after properly updated -
- and see what happens.

Comment: That's basically where I'm at right now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, now it's working all of a sudden after having spent most of the day on this...

What I've done recently is run the **Clean up databases** from the **Control Panel** and rebuild the link database and the search indexes.

So, if you run into this issue try that.

The generated sprite files are located here:

```
\sitecore\shell\client\Sitecore\Speak\Ribbon\Assets\Sprites\Ribbon
```

You should have 3 files:

- `sprite-speak-ribbon-base-ee.css`
- `sprite-speak-ribbon-clean-ee.css`
- `sprite-speak-ribbon-clean-ee.png`

These are generated/refreshed when the Experience Editor is loaded from what I can tell. It's part of the `prepareEditorResources` pipeline defined in `Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.config`.

When it didn't work I only had the first file, but now they are all there.

If you want to check out the sprite "configuration", it is stored in the **Core database** here:

```
/sitecore/content/Applications/WebEdit/Sprites/Experience Editor Speak Ribbon
```

Comment: Just a follow up. I ran through the full upgrade once more and got the same issue. A simple **Clean up databases** and **IIS reset** fixes it.

Comment: A cleanup of the core database followed by an iis reset fixed this issue for me.

Comment: Just ran into this again. Note that the icons may still be missing, even if the three referenced files are in the directory, and match a server that's working.